# Zend Framework: How to remove the DtDd Decorator on a Zend_Form_Element_File?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I've tried every thing I can think of and I can't figure out how to display only the `ViewHelper` decorator on a `Zend_Form_Element_File`.

```
$UserPhoto = new Zend_Form_Element_File('UserPhoto');
$UserPhoto->setDestination(TMP_DIR);
$UserPhoto->addValidator('Count', false, 1);
$UserPhoto->addValidator('Size', false, 10240000); // 10 mb max
$this->addElement($UserPhoto);
```

in my view script:

```
echo $this->form->UserPhoto
```

Which generates

```
<dt>label</dt>
<dd>input element</dd>
```

This is what I want:

```
input element
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest form is:

```
$UserPhoto->setDecorators(array('File'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use 'ViewHelper' instead of 'File'. Not sure why there is no 'ViewHelper' for a File element. =/

Answer (score 2):

This was the only way I could get it to work:

```
$this->addElement($UserPhoto, 'UserPhoto');
$this->UserPhoto->removeDecorator('label');
$this->UserPhoto->removeDecorator('htmlTag'); //DtDd
```